# Image with a chinese filename returns UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have an api backend made of Django Rest Framework and I can not return my Image File with chinese characters like **code/温州银行.png**. It always return the error below:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
>           response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 83, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 448, in raise_uncaught_exception
>       raise exc
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there any way to solve this?

My libraries:

```
Django==1.9.2
djangorestframework==3.5.1
```

My **serializers.py**:

```
class RemitPayeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RemitPayee
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        print 'To Internal Value'
        ret = super(RemitPayeeSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        if data.get('level'):
            ret['level'] = \
                [int(level) for level in data.get('level').split(',')]
        if data.get('bank'):
            ret['bank'] = data.get('bank')
        return ret

    def validate(self, data):
        '''
        '''

        ret = super(RemitPayeeSerializer, self).validate(data)
        request = self.context['request']
        if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT':
            if ret.get('remit_type') != 1 and \
               ret.get('qr_code') is not None:
                form = QRCodeUploadForm(request.data, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                    ret['qr_code'] = form.cleaned_data['qr_code']
                else:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError({
                        'error': [{'QR_code': _('Invalid QR Code')}]})
        return ret

    @is_advpermitted('change_remitpayee')
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        '''
        '''

        member_levels = validated_data.pop('level', None)
        bank = validated_data.get('bank')
        if bank:
            validated_data['bank'] = Bank.objects.get(pk=bank)

        for key, val in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, validated_data[key])
        instance.save()

        if member_levels is not None:
            instance.level.clear()
            for level_id in member_levels:
                level = Level.objects.get(pk=level_id)
                instance.level.add(level)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    @is_advpermitted('change_remitpayee')
    def create(self, data):
        '''
        '''

        member_levels = data.pop('level', None)
        bank = data.get('bank')
        data['bank'] = Bank.objects.get(pk=bank) if bank else None
        remit_payee = RemitPayee.objects.create(**data)

        if member_levels:
            for level_id in member_levels:
                level = Level.objects.get(pk=level_id)
                remit_payee.level.add(level)
        remit_payee.save()
        return remit_payee

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        logger.info('----start-----')
        ret = super(RemitPayeeSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

        request = self.context['request']
        expand = request.GET.get('opt_expand')
        # user, _ = parse_request_for_token(request)
        # member = Member.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        # if member:
        #     ret['remit_limit'] = member.level.remit_limit
        logger.info('----Remit ret-----')
        logger.info(ret)
        bank = ret.get('bank')
        if bank:
            if expand:
                ret['bank'] = {'id': bank['id'], 'name': bank['name']}
            else:
                ret['bank'] = bank['id']

        level = ret.get('level')
        if level:
            member_levels = []
            for x in level:
                if expand:
                    member_levels.append({'id': x['id'], 'name': x['name'],
                                          'remit_limit': x['remit_limit']})
                else:
                    member_levels.append(str(x['id']))
            ret['level'] = member_levels
        return ret
```

My **RemitPayee model**:

```
class RemitPayee(models.Model):
    remit_type = models.IntegerField(
        default=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=REMIT_TYPE_OPTIONS)
    payee_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    memo = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='codes/',
                                null=True, blank=True)
    sum_fund = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(
        default=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS_OPTIONS)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(
        Bank, null=True, blank=True, related_name='remit_payee_bank')
    level = models.ManyToManyField(
        Level, related_name='remit_payee_member_level')
```

Comment: can you show your serializer, please

Comment: I have just updated my question